# How to make datatables export to xls asking for password first before exporting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I was wondering if it is possible to make datatables ask for password first before it is exporting data from datatables to xls file. I tried javascript but apparently datatables uses flash player to export the data to file. So there's no on click event captured in javascript or jquery. Do anyone have the answer? I'll give my code snippet but I don't think it would help. Thanks.

```
    var table = $('.example').DataTable( {
    // dom: '<"col_10 pt_5 pb_5"B><"clear">lf',
    dom: 'B<"pt_5"l>f',
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax:{
      url:'<?php echo site_url().'/student/leads/ajax'; ?>',
      cache: false,
      data: function(d){
        d.startdate = $('#date_from').val(),
        d.enddate = $('#date_to').val()
      }
    },
    iDisplayLength: 20,
    order: [ [ 0, "desc" ] ],
    aLengthMenu: [[20, 50, 100, -1], [20, 50, 100, "All"]],
    aoColumns: [
        {"sTitle": "id", "sWidth": "8%"},
        {"sTitle": "Name", "sWidth": "8%"},
        {"sTitle": "E-mail", "sWidth": "12%"},
        {"sTitle": "Telp", "sWidth": "8%"},
        {"sTitle": "Placement Date", "sWidth": "8%"},
        {"sTitle": "Register", "sWidth": "9%"},
        {"sTitle": "Teacher State", "sWidth": "11%"},
        {"sTitle": "Trial", "sWidth": "7%"},
        {"sTitle": "Study", "sWidth": "13%"}
    ],
    buttons: [
        {
          extend: 'excel',
          text: 'Export to Excel'
        }
    ],
    bAutoWidth: false
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make two button first which will ask to login to database (create form with input users and password) and then if the users is correct you show an other button which gonna let the user download the xls file.